# Gradle, Exclude an Artifact When Uploading to Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I have a Gradle build that runs in Jenkins and Deploys to Artifactory using the Artifactory plugin for Jenkins. I am uploading a `tar.gz` file to Artifactory. The plugin is uploading the `tar.gz` correctly, but it is also uploading a `jar`.

How can I exclude the `jar` so that it is not deployed to Artifactory?

**build.gradle** *(artifacts section)*

```
artifacts {
    archives tar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a jar, maybe you shouldn't use the 'java' plugin?
Take a look at [various base plugins](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/standard_plugins.html#N11CBE), one of them might be a better match.

Comment: I need the `Jar`, it is included inside of the `Tar`. The consumer is expecting a `Jar` in a `Tar`.